# Start IPython notebook server without running web browser?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to use Emacs as main editor for iPython notebooks / Jupyter Notebook (with the package [ein](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-ipython-notebook/#install)). I want to ask you if there is a way to run the server without the need to open a web browser.

Comment: I primarily use VIM. I know Emacs can handle lot more than VIM, which is primarily a text editor. I would love to be able to use vim/emacs to handle both the text editing as well as generate the jupyter notebooks, without leaving the program. Can emacs do that at present?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$ ipython notebook --no-browser
```

**Edit**

Now you should use instead

```
$ jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

Since

> `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
>    You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in the future

Comment: Great! That is exactly what I need, Thanks Cyphase

Comment: Glad I could help @EnricoPirani :). Can you accept this so that the question will be marked as answered?

Comment: I'd appreciate if whoever down-voted this would explain why; I'd love to fix any issues :).

Comment: can you embed graphics and charts in emacs, just like you can in a jupyter notebook in a browser? What does this command do, and how is it different from just starting ipython?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer @Romain. :)

Answer (score 29):

If you don't want to type `ipython notebook --no-browser` all the time,

for ipython 4.0 with jupyter:

1. generate config

   ```
   jupyter notebook --generate-config
   ```

   it would create a file at some place like

   win: `C:\Users\[YouUserName]\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py`

   linux: `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`
2. add `c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False` to this file.

All done!

Comment: Running the script will output something: Writing default config to <path>
Then, you can edit that file with your favorite editor, and either follow the step 2, and add the line, or uncomment the line 
```#c.NotebookApp.open_browser = True```, and set it to False.

Comment: Or can just use `alias jn="ipython notebook --no-browser"`.