# How to run Jupyter notebook without broswer (in different editor)?

Tags: editor, jupyter-notebook

I want the jupyter notebook to use something else than browser. Is there a way to do that? I saw `emacs` can be used but could not understand how to work with it.
If there are any editors that could be easily be setup with jupyter please let me know.

Comment: This is still a good question almost two years later.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you were looking at [Start IPython notebook server without running web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953518/start-ipython-notebook-server-without-running-web-browser). Which specified...

```
$ ipython notebook --no-browser
```

I took a look at the source for notebook and that flag only sets true or false on the following variable

```
open_browser = Bool(True, config=True,
                    help="""Whether to open in a browser after starting.
                    The specific browser used is platform dependent and
                    determined by the python standard library `webbrowser`
                    module, unless it is overridden using the --browser
                    (NotebookApp.browser) configuration option.
                    """)
```

I'd suggest looking at [jupyter/atom-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/atom-notebook). It's likely the closest to what you are asking for, as notebook is designed to be served as a web application.

Comment: if i do `ipython notebook --no-browser` it just says `0 active kernels 
The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/` and actual notebook is not opened.  I will look through the atom-notebook that looks interesting

Comment: hey, I installed `atom` and then the package for `jupyter-notebook` but if i try to open my older `ipynb` they  open as normal scripts and not as `ipy notebook` is there anything more that I should do after the installations ?