# GCP - run all cells of Jupyter Notebook without open browser and show logs to terminal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I started using VM instances in Google Cloud Platform to train deep learning. In a Linux machine what is the best way to start running cells of Jupyter Notebook without opening browser, just by command in terminal. Also I want to see all the output in terminal.

Comment: I think [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953518/start-ipython-notebook-server-without-running-web-browser) can assist you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible and there are different ways of doing it;

One way is to use runipy. This will run all cells in a notebook.

The source code is here [runipy](https://github.com/paulgb/runipy)
You can also save the output as html report or a notebook

You can install runipy using pip

```
$ pip3 install runipy
```

Another method is to use the python3 module nbconvert.

This would allow you to use a python interactive shell.
See the official Python documentation here [Executing notebooks from the command line](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-from-the-command-line)